# What is the best practice for making a WP plugin that I want to develop responsive?

Tags: plugins, design

What is the best practice for making a WP plugin that I want to develop responsive, meaning compatible for all devices?

When writing WP plugin, can you use frameworks like Bootstrap?

Comment: Plugins are meant to add _functionality_. Do you mean a _theme_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its totally up to you. you can use `Bootstrap` or any other UI Framework for styling your plugin. WordPress don't restrict you from using such frameworks but you should keep WP coding standards in mind.